# Normal font in main body counters using classicthesis

Tags: numbering, classicthesis

I am writing my PhD manuscript using classicthesis. I have a few preliminary parts (a summary and a foreword) that I want to include as chapters and sections, but with a different numbering.

I changed the chapter counter using

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\alph{chapter}}
```

before that part, and fixed it so the counter would appear as a *lowercase* letter in the ToC using

```
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\normalfont}
```

It works well, and in the PDF contents from the hyperref package I do get the right behaviour, with lowercase letters as counters, like this

[image: toc_image]

however, in the main body (on page 8) I get this

[image: main_body_image]

and I think some textsc command has overridden the lowercase counter for the chapter. I have tried looking at the tocloft package documentation, to mimick something like the `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{}` command, but I haven't had any luck. The `classicthesis` documentation doesn't help either.

I am sure the fix should be quite easy, but I cannot find it.

An illustration of the problem can be reproduced with the following minimal working example,

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\normalfont}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\alph{chapter}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
Problem: TOC displays Subsection a.1.1., but above it's {\textsc a}.1.1.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document appears to have a lot of "moving parts". It's not straightforward to diagnose the situation, let alone suggest a cure, unless you edit your posting to provide a [Minimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. I realize my question was a big vague, I just added a MWE that reproduces my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `\textsc` that `classicthesis` forces to the section numbers.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[palatino=false]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\normalfont}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\alph{chapter}}

\titleformat{\section}
    {}{\thesection}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
% subsections
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}
% subsubsections
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
TOC displays Subsection a.1.1., which is what we get now.
\end{document}
```

If you still want old style figures, just do `\usepackage{classicthesis}` without option and remove `\usepackage{mathpazo}`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That does it, thanks!